# Hyperlink- Gives Run-Time Error 5 "invalid procedure call or argument"

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, runtime-error

i am trying to create hyperlinks for the range in worksheet "Tables" if only matches with the values on "sheet2" row "b", but gives me "invalid procedure call or argument" error. i was looking online sources for solution but couldn't find anything. Could anyone help me on the following code please;

```
  Sub Macro1()
  For i = 4 To 23
  If Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" Then
  k = Sheets("TABLES").Cells(i, "a").Value
  c = Application.Match(k, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B11:B500000"), 0)
  If IsError(c) Then
  Else
  Sheets("tables").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("tables").Cells(i, "A"), _
                          Address:="", _
                          SubAddress:="sheet2!F" & c, _
                          TextToDisplay:=k
  End If
  End If
  Next i
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Hyperlink Nightmare

```
Option Explicit

Sub Error5()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim c As Variant

    With Sheets("Tables")
        For i = 4 To 23
            If .Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" Then
                k = .Cells(i, "A").Value
                c = Application.Match(k, Sheets("Sheet2") _
                        .Range("B11:B50000"), 0)
                If IsError(c) Then
                  Else
                    .Hyperlinks.Add _
                            Anchor:=.Cells(i, "A"), _
                            Address:="", _
                            SubAddress:="Sheet2!F" & c, _
                            TextToDisplay:=CStr(k)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow!!. Works perfectly, can sleep now lol. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Change `If Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" Then`
To
`If Sheets("TABLES").Cells(i, "a").Value <> "" Then`~
Hope it works then. It is not recognizing object in the First Line.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. when i debug, it gives me the error on the following line: Sheets("tables").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("tables").Cells(i, "A"), _
                          Address:="", _
                          SubAddress:="sheet2!F" & c, _
                          TextToDisplay:=k

Comment: Pl see see the mockup file created by me. It works flawlessly as per your code with this minor change. Please ensure you are are on Table sheet while running program. As objects are not fully defined. hyperlink error<https://www.dropbox.com/s/ruusd97rb2ucdjf/hyperlink_error.xlsm?dl=0>

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. Drives me crazy.lol https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/vzvv83so0m7pfo3bc4h14/Hyperlink-stilldontwork.xlsx?

Comment: Why don't you post the whole code? And a sample of your data. Your variables are wrongly declared.

Comment: Above is the whole code, just sub Macro() and end sub is missing